# Subversion: Synchronize repo with already downloaded project. (Trying to avoid redownload)

Tags: svn

I already have a copy of a `svn` project on my machine and would like to connect it to the `svn` repo and avoid redownload.

I had tried:

```
svn co --depth empty
```

and copying the already downloaded files into it but that didn't work.

Is there a way of doing this or do I really have to delete my local copy and do a `svn` checkout and redownload everything?

Further details:
There are 2 computers and 1 repo, all have the good working copy. 1 computer is linked to svn and has all the .svn metadata and svn status returns up to date. The other computer doesn't have this and I want to link it to the repo without redownloading everything.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have downloaded the project via svn, e.g. from command line:

```
 svn co <URL> .
```

then point yourself in the root dir of the project and write:

```
 svn update
```

which will update your [working copy](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/local/web/subversion/introduction/workingdirectory.html) to the latest version. References:

- [svn checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html)
- [svn update](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html)

Answer (score 0):

i'll recommend you for checking out the project again from repo browser,but you can try this.i assumes that you are having an existing project in your workspace and that project is already a valid working copy.
Select the project you want to connect with SVN and right click to select `Team > Share Project`.

[image]

This will begin the `Share Project wizard`. Select `SVN` as the repository type and click `Next`.

[image]

The wizard will check for valid `.svn metadata` folders in the root of the project you originally selected to share. If it finds those folders, then you will see a screen like the one above. If you do not see this screen, and instead see the screen that you would see when this is a new project, then you should cancel the wizard. This would mean that the wizard did not recognize this as an existing working copy. If you continue, the wizard will treat this like a new project to import into your repository. Otherwise, assuming that you do see the above screen, just click Finish to connect the project with SVN. The wizard will complete the process by launching the commit dialog to commit any locally modified files. You can cancel the dialog if you do not want to commit anything at this time.

Comment: I'm not using eclipse. I'm using straight command line on linux. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> copying the already downloaded files into it but that didn't work.

I'm sorry, but "... that didn't work" is not a description of problem. You have to give more concrete details in form

1. I done ...
2. I expected ...
3. I got ...

co --depth "empty" + copy + update must work for you, with some notes

- `svn co --depth empty URL` is fully correct. You have empty WC, linked to your repository, with only base dir checkouted
- Copy project's tree into your created WC
- Update your working copy in order to sync your tree with repository-tree. Because you want update **tree**, you have to redefine depth for update and subsequent operations with `--set-depth` option: `svn up --set-depth infinity` will be good

Comment: svn up --set-depth infinity tries to redownload and fails because an 'unversioned file/directory of the same name already exists. What I mean by "didn't work" is that when I do a svn status it doesn't say up to date it tells me all my files aren't under version control(they're all ?)